# Why does the foreignkey show up as a dropdown box?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, foreign-keys

Hi Just wondering why when I try to include a foreign key in my model it shows up as a dropdown box rather than a textbox?

Here is my models.py

```
class VolunteerApplication(models.Model):  

    volunteer_name = models.ForeignKey(VolunteerProfile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)`
```

This is what it shows up as on the website

[image: 1]

Comment: Ofcourse it will show us dropdown because foreign key relation is through object not with any text so you have to pass object in that field

Comment: Actually its the feature of Django admin. As the foreign key is defined, means its already created so it's easy to navigate and select.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because its a foreign key. This is default rendering behaviour of the django admin.

The admin screen slows down/refuses to load if there are too many objects that the admin is trying to render in the dropdown.

The problem with raw_id_fields is that it doesn't show the string representation of the selected foreign key. An easy way to see the preview of foreign key without the dropdown - use `django-dynamic-raw-id` package.

https://github.com/lincolnloop/django-dynamic-raw-id

Comment: Oh okay. How do I convert it to a texbox instead of having to do that

Comment: Use the package/library that is mentioned above. That will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In your admin form set your field as a `raw_id_fields`

```py
class AdminForm
    .....
    raw_id_fields = ['volunteer_name']
```

Comment: Why would I include volunteer_number?

Comment: I mean name sorry